# Hibernate - want to put delete and store in one "transaction", if pb occurs, all will be rollbacked

Tags: hibernate, persistence, flush

I have a method which delete some items, and next insert some others items.

```
public void refresh() {
    if (newitems != null) {
        toto.clear();
        for (totoDao p : newItems) {
            toto.store(p);
        }
    }
    newitems = null;
}

public void clear() {
    final Session session = this.getHibernateUtil().getSession();
    int n = session.createQuery(DELETE).executeUpdate();
    session.clear();
    session.flush();
}

public void store(TotoDao object) {         
    final Session session = this.getHibernateUtil().getSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(object);
    session.flush();
}
```

For the moment I have one flush in clear() method and other one in store() method.

I want to add all of theses stuffs in one "transaction", if somethings appears, a application restart just after the toto.clear(), for example, i want that transaction rollback all the block.

So what are the best solution for perfomances and persistances ?

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose these two method calls inside a unique transaction.

Flushing doesn't have anything to do with transactions. It just means "really execute all the SQL statements needed to persist the modifications made in the session". But the commit will only be done at the end of the transaction.

Flushing the session manually is almost always unnecessary. Let Hibernate do it when it has to.

Also, note that a DAO is supposed to be a service object allowing to query and update entities. It's not supposed to be a persistent entity.

Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-flushing

Comment: We have transactionManager, we dont do some beginTransaction().

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

In a singleton class, HibernateUtil, we initialize sessionFactory.

So the issue that i don't know where the transaction begin and finish.

Comment: The transaction starts when a transactional method is called, adn commits or rollbacks at the end of this method It's done by Spring using AOP. Whether a method is transactional or not depends on your Spring configuration, and on the @Transactional annotations. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html?bcsi_scan_554E00F99A9AD604=sSfi6+nA/vZbS4QqRT7ag8pHcBUrAAAApVyyCA==&bcsi_scan_filename=spring-framework-reference.html#transaction-declarative

Answer (score 2):

```
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Transaction tx = null;

try{
     tx = session.beginTransaction();  

    ... your add/store/delete/.... 
    tx.commit();  
}catch(Throwable(or other type of Exception you like) ex){
    tx.rollback();
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't answered the question about rollback. What happens if your add/store/delete throws an exception?

Comment: thanks, then let it be null. :) also the session object was not defined. i just want to show the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Spring has good solutions for [transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html).
On this page you'll find the way to configure spring/hibernate with XML files.

If you need some explanation, just ask and i'll try to help you asap.

Some exemple:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

  <aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="pointcutId" expression="execution(* com.stackoverflow.service.FooService.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="pointcutId"/>
  </aop:config>

  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
      <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
      <!-- other methods (By example Rollback for NullPointerException)-->
      <tx:method name="*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NullPointerException"/>
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
</bean>

 ...

</beans>
```

Comment: thanks but i have already set a solution with transaction annotation with Spring bean.

the only thinks that i've asked me if what mode of @Transaction propagation should i set ;).

Comment: You question wasn't : "So what are the best solution for perfomances and persistances ?"